# Fixing the length (duration) of a webm file takes too much time by ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

I have some webm files which lack duration/length.

For example when I open one of them (which is about 20 minutes) by vlc media player I see something like this:

[image]

This is very annoying because I cannot forward (skip few minutes and advance) through the video.

I was able to fix this problem by ffmpeg using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i original_video.webm -c:a copy new_video.webm
```

But the problem is that this command takes too much time, I am looking for a fast solution using ffmpeg to fix the duration of my webm videos.

If I simply use

```
ffmpeg -i original_video.webm -c copy new_video.webm
```

I get the error:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavcodec     58.101.101 / 58.101.101
  libavformat    58. 51.101 / 58. 51.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'original_video.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x858, SAR 1:1 DAR 640:429, 59.94 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[webm @ 000001c24f3a5c40] Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus 
audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.                                                                         
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): 
Invalid argument                                                                                                           
Stream mapping:                                                                                                                                                                                        
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)                                                                                                                                                                           
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)                                                                                                                                                                             
Last message repeated 1 times
```

Comment: Your command re-encodes the video. Remove the `:a` in `c:a`.

Comment: @Gyan, Thank you, following your comment, I edited my question.

Comment: @llogan I added the complete log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebM only supports VP9/VP8 video. Your input contains H.264 video and is not a compliant WebM file.

Either:

- Re-encode the video to VP9:

  ```
    ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:a copy output.webm
  ```
- Or output to Matroska or MP4 instead of WebM:

  ```
    ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy output.mkv
    ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy output.mp4
  ```

Comment: The ffmpeg copy does a conversion. It still takes 2 seconds for a 2 MB video file but is already faster than the conversion to h264/mp4.